# How to make a function to adress doubly linked list node?

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates, doubly-linked-list

I made an inmplementation of doubly linked list as class in C++

In main.cpp I'm pushing objects of other class into this list like this

```
list.insertBack(ClassA(name, description));
```

But after that I need to change a certain field of this object, for example perform a method that changes population. For that I need to somehow adress this object from the list like I would do with a regular array (smth like `a[i]`). For that I need a special method/function in my List class. How can I implement this?

Comment: Sure, you can implement `operator[]` for your List class. Will it use `find` under the hood? If so, what will you do in the case that `find` returns nullptr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to provide a `operator[]` for your class:

```
template<class T>
class List {

    // your private interface

public:

    // your other public interface 

    T& operator[](unsigned int i)
    {
        Node* n = this->head;
        for (; i>0; --i)
        {
            n = n->next;
        }
        return n->data;
    }
};
```

In your main you can then simply use it like

```
int main() {
    List<double> l;
    l.insertBack(0.0);
    l.insertBack(1.0);
    l.insertBack(2.0);
    l.insertBack(3.0);

    std::cout <<  l[2] << std::endl;
}
```

Note that you might also want a `const` version of this function. Here is a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e74sbz).

**Note:** As pointed out by @Botje, you might also want do some sanity checks on the input. If `i` is equal or larger than the number of existing nodes, my code snippet dereferences a `nullptr` and you get undefined behavior.

Comment: What happens if `i` is larger than the number of nodes in the list?

Comment: @Botje Thank you for pointing this out. Then I am dereferencing ```nullptr``` and it will result in undefined behavior. Like in ```std::vector::operator[]``` I am not doing any checks here.

Comment: Thanks! How can I use this with methods from City class? For example I want to do ```list[2].event()``` which looks like this
```void City::event() {
cout << "Special event happening in city" << this->name << endl;
}```

Comment: @kekundel I updated the answer. It now returns ```T&```. In your case you then get a reference to a ```City``` object.